# How can I add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap from an SSIS Script Task?

Tags: ssis

How can I add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap from an SSIS Script Task? I can add a references to the .dll from regular Visual Studio projects or from Script Coponents. For some reason I am not able reference the .dll from Script Tasks. I tried copying the path from the Visual Studio project but I get an error saying "The file path is not valid". The path on my computer is "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\10.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll".  FYI, I am working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit machine. How can I add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap from an SSIS Script Task? Thanks

Comment: Could you explain **why** you want to reference `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap` from within a Script task?

Comment: I am building a list of IDs that have been inserted, updated, or deleted since the last time the package ran. I have a stored procedure that returns them as a comma separatd list. I wanted to call the stored procedure using a script task since the string was longer SSIS could handle when populating the variable using an Execute SQL task. I ended up doing it with a script task inside a foreach loop container. I am not calling the stored procedure but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add references to your script task in SSIS.  I know that's not what you wanted to hear but the script task does not have the full functionality of a vs project.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Now I can stop banging my head against the wall. I found a workaround. I am building a list of IDs that have been inserted, updated, or deleted since the last time the package was run. I ended up doing it with a foreach loop container.

Comment: @kevin_fitz doesn't know what he is talking about and has clearly never tried it or deployed to a production server.  As if he didn't try just selecting 'Add Reference'?  While referencing libraries 'registered in your GAC' is possible, any libraries they reference not registered will cause errors when trying to run it and that usually happens when deploying to a production environment.  A more constructive comment would have included something in regards to taking a different approach which is something he realized a few years ago.