# SSIS password stripped from connection string in database configuration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ssis

I have a SSIS package that is using SSIS Configuration table in a SQL server to retrieve the connection string property for a OLE DB connection manager.

Thing is that I also need that same connection string to invoke an assembly that uses Entity Framework. I've tried to access the connection manager connection string property but SSIS always strips the password so the connection string goes incomplete to the EF Code First Context and gives login errors.

Any ideas to overcome this?! thanks

Comment: Please show some code. It's impossible to know where you're getting the connection string from.

Comment: In the Script Task, I'm getting the connection string using: Dts.Connections["ConnectionManagerName"].ConnectionString

Comment: And then, how do you get that connection string and pass it to the EF assembly and run whichever is in that assembly? That information is also necessary. please, improve your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already gone another path. It seems that the connection string property in the configuration manager always "hides" the password for security reasons so I'm not reusing that property and instead I'm getting all I need from the SSIS configuration file.

Comment: I always took an approach of using a table to set a Variable. The Variable then set the ConnectionString property on a given Connection Manager. That way I could reference the full connection string without such silly concerns as "security"